# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rsample’

Tags: r

I'm trying to load rsample package in R but i get this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rsample’ in loadNamespace(i, 
c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
there is no package called ‘sfsmisc’
```

I can't not find a solution to this anywhere.

Comment: First thing to try is `install.packages("sfsmisc")`.

Comment: thank you! yes that was the solution. I tried doing this before, but this was before I installed Java SDK8...which i think meant that without it installing sfsmisc did not work. Anyways. Working now! Thank you!

Comment: Can one of you add the solution as an answer so others can be helped if they find this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try install.packages("sfsmisc")

Answer (score 1):

You can download the source file from here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rsample/index.html

I also could not get it to install by simply using install.packages ("rsample").

Reading the reference manual, it imports dplyr, purrr, tibble, rlang, methods, and recipes

Once I installed these, I was able to get the library to load from the local rsample_0.0.2.tar.gz file using the following line.

```
  install.packages ("C:/Users/johndoe/Desktop/rsample_0.0.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```